# Using Spock data driven tests in Grails 3 unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I am upgrading a series of unit tests that worked in Grails 2 to Grails 3 and having problems with domain tests that use the Spock data driven test format to drive tests.

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.Unroll

import com.spiekerpoint.ark.test.ConstraintsTestSupport

 /**
  * Unit test for domain class ContactPhoneNumber.
  */
 @TestFor(ContactPhoneNumber)
 class ContactPhoneNumberSpec implements ConstraintsTestSupport {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    @Unroll
    void "test ContactPhoneNumber type constraints"() {
        when:
        ContactPhoneNumber obj = new ContactPhoneNumber("$field": val)

        then:
        validateConstraints(obj, field, error)

        where:
        error       | field         | val
       'valid'      | 'type'        | 'HOME'
       'valid'      | 'type'        | 'MOBILE'
       'valid'      | 'type'        | 'WORK'
       'valid'      | 'type'        | 'PAGER'
       'valid'      | 'type'        | 'FAX'
    }
}
```

I am getting a 
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException at ContactPhoneNumberSpec.groovy:26

when I execute the test because the test execution is not filling in the error, field and val references in the test. As mentioned, this test works with Grails 2.5.5, so I suspect that I'm missing something that I need in Grails 3.

Edited: I removed the mockForConstraints() call that I originally had in setup() to no effect.

Comment: Follow this http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html and look out for "Testing Constraints". Bottom line `mockForConstraintsTest` is not available any more in Grails 3.

Comment: I had read that section and remove it from another of the test cases. Unfortunately I picked a different test case to paste into the question with it still in. Regardless, removing the mockForConstraintsTests does nothing. It still fails with the MissingPropertyException on the new ContactPhoneNumber line: val is undefined. I'm missing something else that it needs to use the data driven test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the ConstraintsTestSupport trait used was implemented as a class in the old Grails 2.x project and that class extended spock.lang.Specification.  When it was converted to a trait it no longer extended the base Spock class needed to support data driven testing.

The bug was introduced in a completely separate module and it was obvious enough if you look at the code just as a Spock test.